# What's the name of following optimization problem?

Tags: optimization, discrete-optimization, binary-programming

Given a (sparse, or banded if it make things easier) matrix $Q \in \{-1, 0,1\}^{n \times m}$, where $m \gg n$, I want to solve the following optimization problem

$$\max_{v, w \in \{\pm 1\}^n} v Q w^{T}$$

I guess it's in NP. Is there a name or efficient algorithm for this kind of problem? Is it possible to reformulate it as like Max-Cut problem?

Comment: What else do you know about $Q$?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo I can not think of too much right now, It is based on a biological problem called phasing. And I'm try to accelerate it. Algorithm described in https://genome.cshlp.org/content/27/5/757.full.pdf  phasing section. (https://github.com/10XGenomics/supernova/blob/b82c3d8efa68bda2d95f30621cd6d91308ce11a2/lib/assembly/src/10X/Flipper.cc is an model source code )

Comment: Alexandre d'Aspremont, Stephen Boyd, [Relaxations and Randomized Methods for Nonconvex QCQPs](https://web.stanford.edu/class/ee364b/lectures/relaxations.pdf), EE392o, Stanford University, Autumn 2003.

Answer (score 0):

Quadratic Integer Programming.

See [en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_programming) for solution approaches.

Answer (score 0):

While it's not necessarily the most elegant way of stating it, your problem can be stated as a [(quadratically constrained) quadratic program](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratically_constrained_quadratic_program). It can be put in the standard form., Let
$$
\vec{u}=\begin{bmatrix}\vec{v} \\ \vec{w}\end{bmatrix},\ \ \ 
A=\frac 12\begin{bmatrix}0 & Q^T \\ Q & 0\end{bmatrix}
$$
Then the problem is to minimize $\vec{u}^TA\vec{u}$ subject to $u_i^2=1\ \forall i$.

If convenient, it's also possible to change variables/constraints such that the problem is a $\{0,1\}$ quadratic integer programming problem, which may be a bit more standard.
$$
\vec{x}=\frac{\vec{u}+\vec{1}}{2},\ \ \ \vec{a}=\frac{1}{2}A\vec{1}
$$
$$
\text{minimize}\ \ \ \vec{x}^TA\vec{x}-\vec{a}^T\vec{x}
$$
$$
\text{subject to}\ \ \ \vec{x}\in\{0,1\}^{m+n}
$$
It's not totally clear with the constraints, but the complexity almost certainly depends on the definiteness of $A$. If A is indefinite, it is almost certainly NP-hard (w.r.t. letting $m,n\to\infty$ with fixed $m/n$), since it is nonconvex. If A is positive (semi)definite then polynomial time is probably attainable.

Answer (score 0):

With changes of variables $(v+1)/2$ and $(w+1)/2$, this is *quadratic unconstrained binary optimization*: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_unconstrained_binary_optimization

Comment: Hello, I've made some changes.Now the problem in my mind is , is it possible to reformulate is as graph theory problem?